# react map is not rendering all the objects

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

i'm using map to render the values in the object, but i get only the first object value. following is my code for map

```
            {appliedjobs.map((job,index) => {
                 return <ul>
                        <li>{job.jobid}</li>
                        <li>{job.candidatephoneno}</li>
                    </ul>
            })}
```

below is the console output

```
appliedjob: Array(3)
0: {candidatephoneno: "9876543210", jobid: "SVkbFhb30U8Rqx4hNEcx"}
1: {candidatephoneno: "1111111111", jobid: "dj7Q77DHzjSbd7AW89Hq"}
2: {candidatephoneno: "9176837787", jobid: "xtzIqohdx6hekXCiQfhO"}
```

Comment: Can't reproduce your issue. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6acmzuho/) Can you provide example in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Would need more code context to say for sure but you are referencing appliedjobs in the code and appliedjob in your console.  You may also want to wrap the return in ()

Comment: ` render() {
        const {appliedjobs} = this.props
        return (
           <div>
                {appliedjobs.map((job,index) => {
                     return <ul>
                            <li>{job.jobid}</li>
                            <li>{job.candidatephoneno}</li>
                        </ul>
                })}
           </div> 
        );
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return { 
        appliedjobs:state.getAppliedJobs.appliedjob
    }
}`

Comment: return { appliedjobs: state.getAppliedJobs.appliedjob }  implies you are only returning one 'job' from your state.
do you have the reducer code

Comment: but i get all the jobs in the console... the map function is not looping :)

Answer (score 0):

Either use a function to render the `ul` component or directly return the elements.

```js
render () {
  // [...]

  return (
    {appliedjobs.map((job, index) =>
      <ul key={index.toString()}>
        <li>{job.jobid}</li>
        <li>{job.candidatephoneno}</li>
      </ul>
    }
  )
}
```

See: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html